# Http handler is not getting called in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net

I have website which I opened in Visual web developer express.

In web.config , I have a handler defined B.

```
 <add verb="GET,POST" path="*/faq*" validate="false" type="DefaultRedirectHandler" />
```

How to specify the location DefaultRedirectHandler which is a dll in this environment?
I created a handler.dll which contains the class B derived from IHttpHandler in bin directory but there are signs it is not used.

Also, I tried

```
<system.webServer>
        <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
        <handlers>
            <add name="ASP Wild" path="*" verb="*" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="None" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" />
          <add name="SampleHandler" verb="*"
         path="*"
         type="DefaultRedirectHandler,handler.dll"
         resourceType="Unspecified" />

        </handlers>
```

Is there some log I can look at if this handler is called elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

When you add your handler you should fully qualify its type.  Include the namespace along with your type name.

```
<httpHandlers>
  <add verb="*" path="*"
    type="MyHandlerAssembly.With.A.NameSpace.IISHandler1, MyHandlerAssembly" />
</httpHandlers>
```

[How to: Register HTTP Handlers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/46c5ddfy.aspx)

The assembly your handler is in must either exist in your web application's bin directory or the system assembly cache.

For more details on the  configuration for HttpHandler's see the following.

[add Element for httpHandlers (ASP.NET Settings Schema)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7d6sws33.aspx)

Keep in mind that there are many ASP.NET handlers added by default and defined by the system machine.config and root web.config (in your .NET library directory).  If any of these handlers match your path they could be executed first.  If they close the response then your handler may never get executed.

EDIT:

As for debugging what is going on on your server (i.e. what handlers in what order are getting called) you may be interested in checking out [Glimpse](http://getglimpse.com/About).